# How to pass the jQuery object which triggered an event to custom object function?

Tags: jquery, object, parameter-passing

Please take a look at the following code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

Slider = function() {

    this.deleteSlider = function(e) {
        return false;
    }

}

var Slider = new Slider;

$('.heading-slider .actions .delete').click( Slider.deleteSlider );

});
```

I am using jQuery as you see. In this case how to pass the clicked element, wrapped in jQuery object to the deleteSlider function?

The only solution I could come up with is to use `$(e.target)`, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

`Silder.deleteSlider` should be called with `this` pointing to the DOM element that triggered the click regardless of its original context, thus you dont need to do anything other than call `$(this)` from within the function.

If you want specifically call it with `this` referencing the Element wrapped with jquery then you could do:

```
$('.heading-slider .actions .delete').on('click', function(e) {
    Slider.deleteSlider.apply($(this), [e]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is'nt a better way as far as I know, and what's wrong with using `$(e.target)` ??

```
jQuery(function($) {
    Slider = function() {
        this.deleteSlider = function(e) {
            var $elem = $(e.target);
            return false;
        }
    }

    var Slider = new Slider;
    $('.heading-slider .actions .delete').on('click', Slider.deleteSlider);
});
```

Comment: I thought there is a "jQuery-sh" way I don't know about :) Thanks!

Comment: Nope, you can pass a parameter to the deleteSlider function, but that would require another function call in the click function, and be even worse IMO. The event is passed automagically anyway!